# Why is this function always getting called

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax

Tried to do ajax function which calls a php function to do some mysql stuff, however you can see in the log file that the php function updateInfo() is always getting called with every submit button is pressed, despite I never do updateInfo(); in the php.

ajax function (which calls updateInfo();):

```
function showUser(str, name) {

        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else {
            // code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                <?php updateInfo(); ?>
            }
        };
        xmlhttp.open("GET","part.php?q="+str+"&d="+name,true);
        xmlhttp.send();

}
```

php updateInfo function:

```
function updateInfo(){


        error_reporting(0);
    $servername = 'localhost';
$username = 'root';
$password = '';
$dbname = 'defekt';

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die('Connection failed: ' . $conn->connect_error);
} 
    $q = intval($_GET['q']);

$d = $_GET['d'];
$m = preg_replace('/[0-9]+/', '', $d);
$s = intval($_GET['d']);
    $sql = "UPDATE form SET " . $m . "=" . $q . " WHERE id =" . $s;

    $result = $conn->query($sql); 
$conn->close();
}
```

for some reasons I am also not able to echo anything in the updateInfo function.
what would be the best solution to do a specific part in php if you can use functions :)?

Comment: You are trying to call it via javascript looks like. You can't do that, you need to call it in a separate page. The php will run first, then the javascript after the fact.

Comment: @Rasclatt its pretty huge but the updateInfo() function never gets called there, but could it be that javascripts just adds the php code in there to the other php code so, that it basically makes no difference if I write it in javascript or in php the updateInfo(); line? but what could I do else if I just want to run a specifc part in the php code, maybe with ajax action ?

Comment: You need to put the `updateInfo()` in the `part.php` for it to run when you want it to.

Comment: It does not run currently like you have it because there is no `$_GET['q']` or `$_GET['d']` on the page that loads the javascript. The flow is to have `pageA.php` have js that does an ajax call to `pageB.php` where you run your function, then `pageB.php` sends back a response (or not) to `pageA.php`.

Comment: @Rasclatt yeah it actually runs, but it runs on every submit button, but yeah as I said I am just wondering how I can just do a specific part in the part.php  if the showUser function is getting called

Comment: @Rasclatt ah ok I understand know, ok ty